# Elasticsearch Docker, time is not local nor utc?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I'm using official docker image from `FROM docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${VERSION}` .

Time on log file looks like the following

```
 [2019-11-23T15:15:55,553][WARN ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [node-master] [gc][43626] overhead, spent [26.9s] collecting in the last [27.8s]
```

I don't think it is utc, (because it doesn't have `z` in it), and it is not local time.

How do I change the timezone (so that I can see either UTC or local time in the log) in the docker?

Comment: Did it solve your time issue?

Comment: not sure how to check, i added volume option to my docker-compose, based on startup message of ES, it doesn't seem to be working..

Comment: I have the same problem too.. so far did not find any solutions.

Answer (score -1):

The TZ variable does not affect containers.

Try to add `-v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro` to your docker run command.

Comment: elasticsearch docker does not have /etc/localtime nor /etc/timezone, it's missing the tzdata package